# Generate SQL-scheme and copy it to include to WAR-file: problem with plugins' dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin, hibernate3-maven-plugin

Before running integration tests I need to setup database. This include generating SQL-scheme (based on JPA-annotations), save it to file and copy it with other resources to directory which later will be used for creating war file (which will be deployed to Jetty).

So, I use following `hibernate3-maven-plugin` configuration for generating SQL-scheme: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/606229/

To copy resulting `hsql-scheme.sql` from `src/env/test/WEB-INF/classes` to `target/` where it will be packaged to WAR-file I use following: 
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/606230/

But when I run `mvn verify -P test` (yes, all these code inside separate profile) I've got: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/606231/

As you can see `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` does not generate any SQL-scheme and resulting file is empty (in other case we will see it on console also). And this is a problem.

The root of problem (as I understand) is because `hibernate3:hbm2ddl invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase process-resources prior to executing itself`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975465/how-to-call-ant-task-to-process-webapp-files-after-copying-webapp-resources-and) helped me to fix schema' creation:

- call `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` at `prepare-package` phase instead of `generate-resources`
- put result of `hibernate3:hbm2ddl` directly to `target/${build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes`

So, now I still have `hibernate3:hbm2ddl invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase process-resources prior to executing itself` warning, but file `target/${build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes/hsql-scheme.sql` not empty as before.